# Android kotlin Unit test case..?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

How to write the test-cases for the below function.

```
public void trackMaxInterval(int trackingFastestInterval) {
    if (trackingFastestInterval != 0) {
        preferencesManager.writeLong(Constants.INTERVAL, interval);
    } else {
        preferencesManager.writeLong(Constants.INTERVAL, Service.INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

I tried like below code but getting a null point exception it saying PreferencesManager is null

```
@Test
fun shouldSaveTracking_MaxIntervalValue() {
    val preManager: PreferencesManager = mock(PreferencesManager::class.java)
    loginPresenter.trackMaxInterval(2)
    verify(preManager, times(1)).writeLong(Constants.INTERVAL, 2)
}
```

Attached error log.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.track.ui.login.LoginPresenter.trackMaxInterval(LoginPresenter.java:1055)
at com.track.ui.LoginPresenterTest.shouldSaveTracking_MaxIntervalValue(LoginPresenterTest.kt:142)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: `loginPresenter` should be created with the `preManager` in the constructor, or at some point you need to set it if you have a setter/public variable: `loginPresenter.preferencesManager = preManager`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `loginPresenter` object does not hold a reference to a  PreferencesManager instance. Even if you mock your PreferenceMananger in your test, you have to pass it somehow to the `loginPresenter` object.